# What's the advantage/disadvantage of writing `[defaultColor]="'violet'"` in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-databinding

In [angular.io Docs Advanced](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#bind-to-a-second-property) you can read following code:

```
<p [myHighlight]="color" [defaultColor]="'violet'">
  Highlight me too!
</p>
```

I thought that when binding to a constant value, it should be sufficient (and more efficient?) to write

```
defaultColor="violet"
```

Am I wrong? Why would one dynamically bind to a constant value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `defaultColor` is an `@Input()` it's more obvious for the reader of the code because `defaultColor="violet"` could be just an old-style HTML attribute.

Besides that, there is no disadvantage of using the one or the other.

`defaultColor="violet"` is actually added to the DOM while `[defaultColor]="'violet'"` is only visible in the components template because this will be replaced by JavaScript code when the components template is compiled.

If this is an advantage or disadvantage depends on what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Thnx. Are you sure that in case of using `[defaultColor]` there is no overhead of some useless zone.js change detection? Does Angular recognize constant expressions?

Comment: I'm sure it does recognize constant expressions.